# Using sFTP connector on CloudHub

Tags: mule, mule-component, cloudhub

The sFTP connector takes a filepath as input.
If I'm extracting a file as an inputstream to sFTP then I assume I need to save the inputstream as a File and then use the filepath as input for sFTP.

In CloudHub environment, how do I use the File Connector in a 'good' way;
to do this in such a way that it ports easily from localhost to cloudhub?

Thanks for any insight on this.

Comment: Please show your code. Many folks don't have familiarity with the sFTP connector API. For those who do, they may be able to spot your problem immediately.

Comment: I fixed this. The sFTP connector takes an InputStream as input, which I had (I'm working with S3) so I avoided the need for any Files.